# Does KRL support UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, krl

I have an application which targets a Russian audience. Will KRL support UTF-8 Characters in datasources and the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

You don't need to do anything special in your application. UTF-8 should just work. Good luck with your application.